# C# winform, How to create a form ContainerControl?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

Recently I have been researching on how to make your own control. And I have asked in the past (2 days ago) about a Tab Control issue that I am having. Well now I want to create a ContainerControl. Something like the form in the MetroFramework because I want to develop my own custom looking form. So fair this is what I have of the form.

[image: Form Picture]

now the problem that I am having is that this is made inside of the form. There isn't a ContainerControl where I just type in like 1 line of code and my form will look like that. In this solution I will need to type in about 30 lines. So when I mean by container control, you change the form object in the form.cs coding and it will change the design of the form.

Example for metro framework.

```
public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
```

Now if I wanted to create a custom form like the one in the picture. I don't want to add 30 - 50 lines of code per form to do that. I just want to make one form class and then add where the "MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm" is and replace it with my form. For example

```
public partial class Form1 : MyFormExampleNamespace.MyForm
```

And this is what the regular c# winform class structure looks like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

So now that I explained what I want, define what I think a form ContainerControl is, and what I want. How could I accomplish my goal? How would I make a ContainerControl. This is what I have tried before

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GoatUserControls
{

public class GoatForm : Form
{

    public GoatForm()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        base.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // GoatForm
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Name = "GoatForm";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.GoatForm_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private void GoatForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //protected override BorderStyle()
    //  {

    //  }

}

}
```

And this is what I have in the main form

```
public partial class Form1 : GoatUserControls.GoatForm
```

So how would I make a form ContainerControl?

Comment: That's called a base class; it has nothing to do with `ContainerControl`.  And your code should work fine; what's the problem?

Comment: Oh okay sorry I just started programming user controls and the website said that it was a ContainerControl well to me. The base class doesn't change any options of the form or doesn't seem to load.

Comment: You haven't set any options.  What do you expect to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: Okay now that I know the name of what it is (Form Base Class) I clearly need to research more XD. Thanks

Comment: Braydel, you are trying to use inheritance.  But your user control needs to be of the same type.  So if you create a custom form that you want to use for all your forms, then add a new form to your solution and make the changes you want.  Then any new form you add, in the code you can inherit from your base form like `public partial class Form1 : Form2` Forms are different than user controls and my guess is you made a user control and are trying to inherit it from your form.

Comment: How would I change the text of a form attached to the form? This is what I have http://pastebin.com/qKzJUuaf

Comment: What a friendly welcome the `Text` property says to users!

Comment: Yeah I immeatly changed that XD it was a joke to my friend

Comment: I shared an answer for you. It's a good start point and you can make it more mature by writing suitable codes to move the form using the new title bar or adding codes for toggle windows state by double click on new title bar.

Comment: You can search about the tasks like, moving border-less form or toggling window state. If you didn't find any suitable answer which fits the requirement, feel free to ask new question about requirements and share your efforts :)

Comment: So I already have a method to move a border less form and how to re size it. And I don't really like your method because I won't be able to use custom buttons. I am just trying to figure out how to override form properties. Like text or stuff like that. I figured out how to override the background color with the MetroFramework example.

Comment: What don't you like exactly about the answer? Which method does disable you to have custom buttons? You asked a way to create custom title-bar for your forms and not write the code for all of your forms and here is a good idea about doing what you need. No problem, it seems you don't need the answer anymore.

Comment: The tool strip options looks like it won't allow me to add my custom buttons so I wanted to make a form and figure out how to change the text of the form from the base form. So fair I can control the background color by overriding the OnPaintBackground event. So how can I change the form text from the base form?

Comment: Btw I use 3 custom buttons that displays only the image and have events to change the image when your mouse is over it, form not selected, etc. And the text of the form is on a label of the form on the header panel. The label displays the Form1.text property so basically im asking how can I change Form1.text from the base class.

Comment: Another question is how do I get Form1 width from the base form? I tried using Width and base.Width and it is returning the base width.

Comment: @Braydel Here in stack overflow when you create a post and ask a question, you should keep the question about a single specific topic. Instead of asking multiple questions in a single post, create multiple posts and then in each post ask a single question. This way more people can help you. Also small problems will solve sooner than big complex problems. Now you are asking many questions in this post and your comments. To learn more read: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

Comment: @Braydel Also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Braydel Also when answering comments of other users, notify them using  by using @ as I used at the beginning of these last comments.

Comment: @Braydel Hope my comments make you use the site better and helps you to receive more help to solve problems. Also if you made the question of this post more specific, let me know to share an answer for you. Or let me know if you posted a new question and I as a community member will try to help you :)